# Bash While Read

Tags: bash, loops, while-loop

Have a number of files in a directory that I want to process. Each file has a name which I need to use in order to set a NAME value and each file has a list of IP addresses in it which I need to do something to.

```
     #!/bin/bash
     TMPDIR=/usr/customer/scripts/tmp
     ip_targets(){
        OLD_IFS=$IFS
        while IFS= read -r file_name; do
            log "This is: $file_name"
        done < "$(find "$TMPDIR" -regex '.*.vms$')"
        IFS=$OLD_IFS
     }
     ip_targets
```

If I run:

```
$find /usr/customer/scripts/tmp -regex '.*.vms$'
```

I get:

```
/usr/customer/scripts/tmp/XXX.vms
/usr/customer/scripts/tmp/YYY.vms
```

each of which has a list of IP's.

If I run the script I get:

```
$ bash -x tester.sh
+ TMPDIR=/usr/customer/scripts/tmp
+ ip_targets
+ OLD_IFS='
'
++ find /usr/customer/scripts/tmp -regex '.*.vms$'
++ find /usr/customer/scripts/tmp -regex '.*.vms$'
tester.sh: line 4: /usr/customer/scripts/tmp/XXX.vms
/usr/customer/scripts/tmp/YYY.vms: No such file or directory
+ IFS='
'
```

Firstly I would like to be able to pass the name of just the file with no path nor extension.

Secondly I would like to add a further section which then allows a command to be issued to each of the IP's in each file.

Comment: Could you just `cat /user/customer/scripts/tmp/*.vms | <your command to do to the piped ips>` so you don't have to monkey with loops?

Comment: @JNevill - Need to actually understand how to do it using while read since  the real thing I need to do isn't as simple.

Comment: Since you at using `while IFS= ` you do not need `OLD_IFS`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are appending the set of files to a long string.

```
< "$(find "$TMPDIR" -regex '.*.vms$')"
```

You should stream 1 file. This can be done by something like

```
< <(cat $(find "$TMPDIR" -regex '.*.vms$'))
```

EDIT
When you want the filenames and not the content, make a virtual file with the filenames (process substitution) using

```
< <(find "$TMPDIR" -regex '.*.vms$')
```

Comment: If I try this I get the contents of each line of each file parsed. I need to first parse the name of each file.